# How to use Web Speech API in Kotlin Multiplatform for web application

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

Do you know how to use Web Speech API in KMM project for Web application: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API/Using_the_Web_Speech_API

I'm using Kotlin to build the web app, and the web app require speech to text feature.

Comment: What exactly do you fail to do?

Comment: I don't know what to do from the scratch. Building the web app is ok for me, but how to use SpeechRecognition from Web Speech Api

Comment: You can try to find the JavaScript code and rewrite it with Kotlin.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with this particular WEB API, but here's the general process of wrapping global JS APIs in Kotlin so hopefully you'll be able to correct the odd inconsistencies yourself via trial and error.

Firstly, since the target API is global, there's no need for any meta-information for the compiler about where to source JS code from - it's present in the global context. Therefore, we only need to declare the shape of that global context. Normally that would be a straightforward task as outlined in this [article](https://dev.to/mpetuska/js-in-kotlinjs-c4g), however there's a caveat here which requires some trickery to make it work on all the browsers:

> As mentioned earlier, Chrome currently supports speech recognition with prefixed properties, therefore at the start of our code we include these lines to feed the right objects to Chrome, and any future implementations that might support the features without a prefix:
>
> ```js
> var SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || webkitSpeechRecognition;
> var SpeechGrammarList = window.SpeechGrammarList || webkitSpeechGrammarList;
> var SpeechRecognitionEvent = window.SpeechRecognitionEvent || >webkitSpeechRecognitionEvent;
> ```

But let's ignore that for now since the API shape is consistent across the implementation, and name is the only difference that we'll address later. Two main API entities we need to wrap here are `SpeechRecognition` and `SpeechGrammarList`, both being classes. However, to make it easier to bridge the inconsistent names for them later on, in Kotlin it's best to describe their shapes as `external interface`s. The process for both is the same, so I'll just outline it for [SpeechRecognition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition).

First, the interface declaration. Here we can already make use from EventTarget declaration in Kotlin/JS stdlib. Note that the name of it does not matter here and will not clash with `webkitSpeechRecognition` when present since we declare it as an interface and as such we only care about the API shape.

```kotlin
external interface SpeechRecognition: EventTarget {
  val grammars: SpeechGrammarList // or dynamic if you don't want to declare nested types
  var lang: String
  // etc...
}
```

Once we have the API shape declared, we need to bridge naming inconsistencies and provide a unified way to construct its instances from Kotlin. For that, we'll inject some hacky Kotlin code to act as our constructors.

```kotlin
// We match the function name to the type name here so that from Kotlin consumer's perspective it's indistinguishable from an actual constructor.
fun SpeechRecognition(): SpeechRecognition {
  // Using some direct JS code to get an appropriate class reference
  val cls = js("window.SpeechRecognition || webkitSpeechRecognition")
  // Using the class reference to construct an instance of it and then tell the kotlin compiler to assume it's type
  return js("new cls()").unsafeCast<SpeechRecognition>()
}
```

Hopefully this gives you the general idea of how things tie together. Let me know if something's still not quite clear.